# Checking if Element has Style Defined, not from Default Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way, using JavaScript, that I could deduce whether an element has a specific CSS definition applied to it, that wasn't inherited from the browser's stylesheet?

I need to know whether a given element has had its `position` definition *explicitly* defined (explicitly being a definition not from the browser's stylesheet).

What'd initially come to mind is executing an algorithm to compare said element's style definition with the default style definition for the same element. However, the scenario where the same definition as the default definition (defined in default stylesheet) is also important.

Say the element in question is a `div`. The default `position`ing, across browsers, is `static`. If it's value is `absolute` or `relative`, the answer's easy. But, if it's `static`, there's no "easy" way, that I know of, to determine if it was a 'user supplied styling' (stylesheet or inline-style).

Thinking of something akin to `object.hasOwnProperty`. However, in this case, it'd be called on the classlist and a property will be passed as a parameter; with a boolean return value indicating if the property has been set by a 'user defined definition'?

Comment: Inspect the element, look at the rules applied to it in the console.

Comment: @guest271314 what does that matter? the use case can be any element.

Comment: @epascarello i need this in code. i know how to use devtools ...

Comment: @culturalanomoly Different elements have different default styles . Tried creating new element having existing element `tagName` using `document.createElement()` , compare default style of created element with existing element ?

Comment: @guest271314 i'm aware that different elements have different default styles. i'm looking for a novel solution to find out whether the element has had it's `position` property set, not by the default stylesheet.

Comment: _"looking for a novel solution "_ Can define "novel" ? Can include `html` at Question , create  stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Tried comapring newly created element style to existing element style ?

Comment: @guest271314 no need for a fiddle, question is adequate; stop the trolling. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novel

Comment: Hi, is it ok using jQuery ? Maybe you could run something like `$('element').attr('style')` and then evaluate the string you get as a result to see if it contains "position:".

Comment: @culturalanomoly Not "trolling" . Attempting to clarify actual Question , what have tried to solve Question ?

Comment: _"However, the scenario where the same definition as the default definition (defined in default stylesheet) is also important."_ How is this to be determined ?

Comment: @groooves jquery is fine (i can decompile the necessary bits). does `$('element').attr('style')`  return only 'user-defined' values?

Comment: @guest271314 now you understand the question. happy i've clarified it ..

Comment: @culturalanomoly _"haven't gotten a +1 for this question yet. guess that'll come soon enough. "_ ? What have you tried ?

Comment: @guest271314 don't try that "what have you tried bs on this one." have i written code today? more than you? likely yes. have i written code to specifically address this issue, no; i don't need to. this is experimental. i've done research and am quite knowledgeable on the topic. i don't need to be spoon-fed with a coded solution. looking for an approach/bone from my peers. i think we're on topic here. let this question cook here and stop the misdirection/spam.

Comment: @culturalanomoly _"have i written code to specifically address this issue, no; i don't need to. this is experimental."_ ? No "misdirection" , or "spam" . Direct , here . Only attempting to determine context , expected result . If interpret Question correctly , would perhaps try `window.getComputedStyle()` , `getBoundingClientRect()` at before loading any stylesheets or link elements

Comment: Save `style` element text , remove style element text , then load complete document , compare differences . i.e.g, see https://github.com/guest271314/toggleStyles

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @torazaburo how does an absolutely position element get positioned, in relation to what element? its positioned in relation to its closest ***explicitly*** `position`ed parent.

Comment: @culturalanomoly I don't believe that's correct. Positioning has nothing to do with whether the position value of the offset parent was set via a default or explicitly. In any case, if you want to find the offset parent, why not use `offsetParent`?

Answer (score 1):

All elements have a standard position property of `static`. You can use that knowledge in conjunction with [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to deduce whether the element has a custom defined position:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('....');
if (window.getComputedStyle(elem, null) !== 'static') {
    // The element has custom position defined in either .style in via a css rule
}
```

This has the obvious crux that it does not catch the case when you specifically an element's position to be static. To do that efficiently, you'd have to see which CSS styles apply for your specific element and see if any of them is 'position'. You can use something like: https://github.com/Box9/jss to get that. (there used to be window.getMatchedCSSRules, but that's deprecated)

If you don't want to use a library to achieve this, you can manually parse all the `document.styleSheets` for `rules` and see if the `selectorText` matches your element.

This is just a method I wrote up in 5 minutes and works pretty fine (though take care, this is not the most performant method in the world):

```
function getStylesForElement (elem) {
    var result = {};

    [].slice.call(document.styleSheets).forEach(function (stylesheet) {
        // some stylesheets don't have rules
        if (!stylesheet.rules) return;
        [].slice.call(stylesheet.rules).forEach(function (rule) {
            // account for multiple rules split by a comma
            rule.selectorText.split(',').forEach(function (selector) {
                if (elem.matches(selector)) {
                    for (var index=0; index < rule.style.length; ++index) {
                        var prop = rule.style[index];
                        result[prop] = rule.style[prop];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```